# Unable to read uncommited data using Spring JPA READ_UNCOMMITTED isolation level

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, transactions, spring-transactions

I have two JPA repository methods, one method updates the record and goes for `I/O` operation. Another method reads a record from the Postgres database, but here I want to allow dirty read.

The below code is experimental, not production-grade one.

Controller endpoints to trigger JPA repository methods:

```
@GetMapping( "update" )
public String updatePerson( ) throws InterruptedException {
    return managerService.updatePerson();
}

@GetMapping( "read_uncommitted" )
public String getUncommited( ) {
    return personService.readUncommited();
}
```

JPA Repository methods:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public String updatePerson( ) throws InterruptedException {
    Person person = entityManager.find(Person.class, 55L);
    person.setName("Chuck Norris");
    entityManager.persist(person);
    entityManager.flush();
    Thread.sleep(15000); // imitating I/O behaviour
    return person.getName();
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly = true, isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED )
public String readUncommited() {
    Person person = entityManager.find(Person.class, 55L);
    return person.getName();
}
```

In `updatePerson()` I am updating person object, flushing the record, I believe `transaction` will be committed once method call completes i.e. record will remain in uncommitted state due `Thread.sleep`

Now in  `readUncommitted()` I am trying to read the same record just a moment after triggering the `updatePerson()`. The method is annotated with `Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED`, but  I am unable to read the above updated-uncommitted record.

Comment: Postgres does not support read uncommitted. It will never allow dirty reads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL standard defines `READ UNCOMMITTED` by not defining any isolation guarantees for it. In other words, it does not require that you actually get to see uncommitted data in that isolation level.

PostgreSQL takes advantage of that by accepting `READ UNCOMMITTED`, but actually giving you `READ COMMITTED`.

Databases that operate with read locks usually use `READ UNCOMMITTED` to work around that limitation, but it is difficult to come up with use cases in PostgreSQL.